# How to change guava cache eviction strategy using weigher

Tags: java, caching, guava

Hello I have this simple mem cache using guava on Android for images

```
memCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumWeight(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/MEMORY_POOL)
                .weigher(new Weigher<String, Bitmap>() {
                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    public int weigh(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
                            return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
                        } else {
                            return bitmap.getByteCount();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .removalListener(new RemovalListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<String, Bitmap> objectObjectRemovalNotification) {
                        final Bitmap bitmap = objectObjectRemovalNotification.getValue();
                        if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                            Log.debug("Cache: recycling bitmap");
                            bitmap.recycle();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

When item is removed from cache, it removes the items that were not used for longest time first. I would like to change this so that is removes first items with biggest weight. Is it possible ?

Comment: The [`CacheBuilder` javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) does specify that the eviction when a maximum size (or weight) is reached is an LRU-based one. It also says (for `maximumWeight()`) _"Note that weight is only used to determine whether the cache is over capacity; it has no effect on selecting which entry should be evicted next."_.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Ehacache](http://ehcache.org/) for this task. The desired functionality can be implemented by:

1. Overriding `isExpired()` method of [`Element`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/Element.html) class (and providing your weight logic in there). Then, instead of adding usual `Element`s to the cache, add instances of your extended class.
2. Attaching [`CacheEventListener`](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-event-listeners).

It might require a bit more configuration than Guava but nonetheless should work.